# QGLWidget::renderPixmap() failed ---QGLContext::chooseContext() : SetPixelFormat failed

Tags: qt, opengl

I want to call QGLWidget::renderPixmap() to save out contents of a QGLWidget, but it fails. The console prompts:
"QGLContext::chooseContext() : SetPixelFormat failed: Incorrect function."

```
void MyOpenGLWidget::savePicture()
{
    QPixmap pixmap = renderPixmap(width(), height());
}
```

Running environment:
Windows Xp, QtSDK 4.8.0

Comment: Seems like C++ code, you should add this tag to your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `renderPixmap` states that:

> Note that the creation of display lists, modifications of the view
>   frustum etc. should be done from within initializeGL(). If this is not
>   done, the temporary QGLContext will not be initialized properly, and
>   the rendered pixmap may be incomplete/corrupted.

So I am guessing that parts of your context configuration is in different methods to `initializeGL()`.

Another scenario that could cause your problem is if you are using a custom `QGLContext` and have not overridden `QGLContext::choosePixelFormat(void * dummyPfd, HDC pdc)`.